# Extracting part of string in a dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe which has lines as below in a single column:

`__label__JCB_Spare_Part  __label__Differential_Housings jcb  casting  assy  differential  housing
__label__Vibrating_Roller  __label__Road_Roller double  drum  mini  roller  seat  drive  model  fyl  engine  nbsp  hp  aircolled  diesel  engine  wheel  size  walk  speed  km  climbing  capacity  drive  hydrostatic  drive  nbsp  nbsp
__label__Vibrating_Roller  __label__Road_Roller double  drum  mini  roller  seat  drive  model  fyl  engine  nbsp  hp  aircolled  diesel  engine  wheel  size  walk  speed  km  climbing  capacity  drive  hydrostatic  drive  nbsp  nbsp
__label__Crawler_Dozer  __label__Bulldozer dozer  bulldozer
__label__Crawler_Dozer  __label__Bulldozer dozer  bulldozer`

I wish to extract all the words with prefix equal to `__label__` in a separate column as below:
`__label__JCB_Spare_Part  __label__Differential_Housings
__label__Vibrating_Roller  __label__Road_Roller
__label__Vibrating_Roller  __label__Road_Roller
__label__Crawler_Dozer  __label__Bulldozer
__label__Crawler_Dozer  __label__Bulldozer`

What I have tried:
`labels = input[0].str.extract(r'(__label__[\w]+)')`
but it only pulls out a single first label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is mostly correct; it's just that you want `findall` instead:

```
labels = input[0].str.findall(r'(__label__[\w]+)')
```

Comment: Thanks @gmds, didn't know about findall() in str objects. btw \w contains underscore, right??

Comment: @hacker315 my mistake; you are right. \w *does* contain underscores, so it's just about `findall` vs `extract`. I have edited that part of the answer out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re

str = """
__label__JCB_Spare_Part  __label__Differential_Housings jcb  casting  assy  differential  housing
__label__Vibrating_Roller  __label__Road_Roller double  drum  mini  roller  seat  drive  model  fyl  engine  nbsp  hp  aircolled  diesel  engine  wheel  size  walk  speed  km  climbing  capacity  drive  hydrostatic  drive  nbsp  nbsp
__label__Vibrating_Roller  __label__Road_Roller double  drum  mini  roller  seat  drive  model  fyl  engine  nbsp  hp  aircolled  diesel  engine  wheel  size  walk  speed  km  climbing  capacity  drive  hydrostatic  drive  nbsp  nbsp
__label__Crawler_Dozer  __label__Bulldozer dozer  bulldozer
__label__Crawler_Dozer  __label__Bulldozer dozer  bulldozer
"""

result = re.findall('__label__\w+', str)
```